# Cognos Report Studio 10.2 multiple reports from one master

Tags: multiple-columns, cognos

We are needing to build a huge amount of reports, but alot of the metrics and fields are duplicated. Is it possible to build 1 (or a few) report to incorporate everything, and then based on what 'report' is requested to be run by the user, it hides/shows certain fields?

e.g. master report contains columns 1-100

user 1 needs to run report A, which uses columns 1-20, so hides columns 21-100
user 2 needs to run report B, which uses columns 21-40, so hides columns 1-20 and columns 41-100

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.
Go to condition explorer and create a string variable based on

```
#sq($account.defaultName)#
```

Create values for all possible usernames.
Use this variable as a **Style variable** and set up report presentation (show/hide columns) for all values.

And think about using groups not named users with

```
#CSVIdentityNameList()#
```

It will be more complicated but you won't stick to chosen usernames.

Comment: Sorry I should have added, (quite a big piece of the puzzle so I do apologise) we do not have access to any permissions, groupings, or SQL. Our data is administered off site. Would this still work if I can get hold of usernames? I was thinking more along the lines of something on a prompt page?

Comment: If you log in with different names and anonymous log in disabled, you have usernames.
But yes, you can create variable based on prompt parameter. Use Value prompt with static choice filled.

Answer (score 0):

I would create report views pointing to the single report, one for each version of the report you want to run. Each view would pass in a different static value for a common parameter, say 'reportType'. The report would then use this static value to change the output returned to the user. This can be accomplished with hiding columns as Alexey suggested or you can create multiple pages and use a render variable that tests the value of the 'reportType' parameter and renders the appropriate page. The benefits of this approach as opposed to hiding is easier maintenance and a potential performance improvement as non-displayed columns are not retrieved from the data source, especially if the non-displayed columns force expensive unnecessary joins.